# Cannot read property 'getPayload' of undefined

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-oauth

I am implementing OAuth Google Sign in using backend  (written in node.js, express framework at Heroku). Front end is Android and it sends the token id to the server just fine. And server receives the token id correctly.

Here is the code (which is ripped off straight from Google Documents)

```
var auth = new GoogleAuth;
var client = new auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, '', '');
    client.verifyIdToken(
        token,
        CLIENT_ID,
        // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
        //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3],
        function(e, login) {
            var payload = login.getPayload();
            var userid = payload['sub'];
            // If request specified a G Suite domain:
            //var domain = payload['hd'];

        });
```

But at times login in undefined. Its so strange that this problem occurs 1/10 rather than for every try so that I am not able to track the source of issue. For every other 9/10 it works just fine.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are not checking if your callback get's any error.

The standard way in node.js to use a callback function is using two parameters - error is the first, the actual (success) returned data is the second, and the convention is that if an error exists - you should address it, and you're not gauranteed to get the data, and if everything went well- error will be null and you'll get your data.

So in your code, you are not checking that there's an error (and like you say, not always there's one).
Should be something like:

```
function(e, login) {
  if (e) {
     // handle error here
    return; // don't continue, you don't have login 
  }
  // if we got here, login is defined
  var payload = login.getPayload();
  var userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //var domain = payload['hd'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to the callback function is an error that needs to handled.

```
    function(error, login) {
        if (error) return console.error(error)
        var payload = login.getPayload();
        var userid = payload['sub'];
        // If request specified a G Suite domain:
        //var domain = payload['hd'];

    });
```